# How do we ask about something bad happened?

Tags: expressions

How do i ask my friend about her facebook account that disappeared?
Do I say: " what's wrong"?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by 'happen suddenly.'

Comment: I elborated it @Pyraminx

Comment: It depends on what "something" is? Good, bad, or some special situation can have different responses.

Comment: Did the bad thing happen recently, like spilled milk, or is it something long-term, like a broken arm?

Comment: For example my friend's facebook account disappeared. Then i write to her to ask her about the matter. How do i ask?

Comment: If a Facebook account disappears, you say, "What happened?" (or maybe "What went wrong?")

Comment: Ok @ J.R ;  i think now that my comments made the question specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's typical to choose what you say based on what you already know or can immediately observe.  If you were in the other room and heard a large noise you might come in and ask, "What was that?" or "What happened?"
If you see a child trip and fall, you might ask, "Are you okay?" or "Are you hurt?"
If someone is crying and you don't know why, you might ask, "What's wrong?" or "Why are you crying?"
If you see a child screaming and yelling, you might ask, "What's all the yelling about?"

There really is no one single way to ask "What's wrong?"

Comment: Wording might also depend on how well you know the person as well or how involved you wish to become in the problem.

Comment: @scrappedcola- good points as well.

Comment: @scrappedcola would you give me examples?

Comment: For example my friend's facebook account disappeared. Then i write to her to ask her about the matter. How do i ask?

Comment: Say you have a close relative that looks sad and you can guess possibly something bad has happened to you might say: "I noticed you look sad. Is there something wrong? How can I help you out?" You take interest in their feelings, asking for details, and a way to make things better. But if it's someone you know in passing you might ask "Are you ok?" which doesn't go for details and gives the speaker an escape of a short non-detailed answer. It kind of convey's a passing interest but not a deeper attachment.

Comment: "Hey <your friends name here> did you recently close your facebook account?" Just because it disappeared doesn't imply something bad happened they could have just decided to close it or it could be forced by facebook.

Comment: Thank you so much for the rich explanation @scrappedcola